# Why does someone else's notifications come up on my Twitter account for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, twitter

I let my friend sign into Twitter on my iPhone and we deleted her account afterwards. After that, all her notifications, such as mentions and messages still come up on my iPhone. It’s really annoying. How can I get it to stop doing that?

Answer (score 7):

In a nutshell - your phone asked to be notified and never cleaned up that request (or the clean up request didn't get processed correctly.)

If you simply uninstall the application and wait (perhaps using a different iOS twitter app in the meantime), the system will remove your device from that notification queue once it misses enough deliveries of a notification. This takes a variable amount of time, so you might want to force the issue by logging back in as your friend and removing the request to send notifications to your iPhone.

According to [this thread on the Apple support forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3407167?start=0&tstart=0), here’s that fix:

1. Log in with the previous account in Twitter settings.
2. Go to the Twitter apps’s “accounts” page.
3. Click “Settings” (bottom left).
4. Edit the notifications of the previous account by switching to “off” for “mentions and replies” and “message”.
5. Finally, delete the account again.

Comment: This is correct since the notifications are being sent from the twitter servers to Apple and addressed to a specific device. It doesn't really matter that on your phone another account is now present. You'll need to "unsubscribe" as explained above or wait for the failed message count to reset that "channel" as being undeliverable over time.

Comment: What if you cant reach them? What do i do then..?

Answer (score 1):

Sign into Twitter on your computer using the other person's account, or send them these instructions.

Go to Settings, then Apps (left hand side), then click on 'Learn how to revoke an iOS app', read 'How to revoke access to the iOS 5 integration from the web' and follow the instructions.

Go back to the Twitter web page. Click 'Revoke access' next to iOS 5 Twitter integration, and then you're done.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the account in Settings.
2. Remove the Twitter app.
3. Rurn your phone off for a couple minutes.
4. Turn it back on reinstall the Twitter app.

The problem should be gone!

I tried everything and this finally fixed it.